# Unreliable sensor values from Cordova-device-orientation plugin on Android devices

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I have written my hybrid phone app using the Meteor platform. And I am getting sensor values using the plugin  [Cordova-device-orientation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device-orientation/index.html).

This is the javascript code:-

```
function onSuccess(heading) {
    var element = document.getElementById('heading');
    element.innerHTML = 'Heading: ' + heading.magneticHeading;
};

function onError(compassError) {
    alert('Compass error: ' + compassError.code);
};

var watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError);
```

The problem with the above code is that the heading value that I get is not always correct. The values are inconsistent across phones, on some very few devices it works absolutely fine but on most devices the values suddenly jumps randomly so to me it doesn't look like the problem is with the phone's hardware but it is with the cordova plugin itself. The plugin provided by cordova to get device orientation is it's [official plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device-orientation/index.html)  yet it is highly unreliable.

So is there a way of getting perfect sensor values for Meteor(hybrid) app or am I doing something wrong in my current code?

Answer (score 1):

I find the compass heading notoriously unreliable on Android. You can compare what this plugin reports with what a compass app or a map app displays.

For me, when the compass heading reporting in my app is off, the compass heading reported by the map or compass app is also off. Sometimes horribly so.

Your code is correct.